# Change the number of color depends on which is hovered

Tags: html, css, hover

I have this table:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td class="order-delivered"><i>order</i><br/><i>delivered</i><br/>
                    <a class="check-mark">✔</a>
                </td>
                <td class="prep-pizza"><i>prep</i><br/><i>pizza</i><br/>
                    <a class="check-mark">✔</a>
                </td>
                <td class="bake-pizza"><i>bake</i><br/><i>pizza</i><br/>
                    <a class="check-mark">✔</a>
                </td>
                <td class="out-for-deliver"><i>out for</i><br/><i>delivery</i><br/>
                    <a class="check-mark">✔</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

What I want is that when I hover in class `prep-pizza`, it will change the text color of `a` in `prep-pizza` and `order-delivered`.

And when I hovered on `bake-pizza` it will change the text color of `a` in `prep-pizza` and `order-delivered` and `bake-pizza`

and lastly when I hovered in `out-for-deliver` it will change the text color of `a` of all the `td`.

And by the way the **check mark** is only colored not the other characters.

How can I implement this kind of hovering where it will target multiple `a` from different class.

EDIT:

it will change color depending of the current location of which they currently hovering.

When I only hover `order-delivered` it will only change to the of the `order-delivered`.

Comment: So what you want is to colour all of the previous-siblings of the item you are currently hovering over... ?

Comment: @TarynEast no, added edit above.

Comment: @JoshCrozier can you give me a specific link to my problem? thx

Comment: Ok so the colour is changed for "the current item plus any previous siblings"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope I understand what you want,
this should do the trick

```
tr:hover .check-mark,
td:hover .check-mark {
    color: blue;
}

td:hover ~ td .check-mark {
    color: black;
}
```

try it here http://jsfiddle.net/1n75v7y1/

Comment: That's awesome, but I'm finding it hard to figure out why it works (my CSS-fu is only "satisfactory")... can you explain the two style-pieces and how they work together?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS, it can only change the current hover element... if you need to change another sibilings then you need to use javascript or jquery

```
.order-delivered:hover{
background-color: red;
}
.prep-pizza:hover{
background-color: red;
}
.bake-pizza:hover{
background-color: red;
}
.out-for-deliver:hover{
background-color: red;
}
```